# Why is the electric component of a light field more important than the magnetic component?

Tags: electromagnetism, optics

This is the common impression.

But, is it just a rule of thumb and correct only in some wavelength region or does it hold universally?

Comment: Potential duplicate: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/44863/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is more important in the sense of accelerating charged particles.

In vacuum, it is easy to show that the ratio of the amplitudes of the electric field and magnetic field is $c$ (in SI units).

The Lorentz force on a charged particle is
$$\vec{F} = q (\vec{E} + \vec{v} \times \vec{B})$$

If we just consider the magnitudes of the electric versus the magnetic forces acting on a charged particle, then (for a charge in vacuum), we can see that
$$ \frac{F_B}{F_E} = \frac{v}{c}$$

Thus unless the charges are moving relativistically then it is the electric part of the Lorentz force that is dominant.

In a conducting material, the balance between electric and magnetic fields changes. In a very good conductor then then
$$\frac{E}{B} = \left( \frac{\omega}{\mu_0 \mu_r \sigma}\right)^{1/2} = c\left( \frac{\omega \epsilon_0}{\sigma}\right)^{1/2},$$
with a a phase difference of $\pi/4$ between the E- and B-fields. In general this ratio will be $\ll c$ in a good conductor where $\sigma \gg \omega \epsilon_0$.

Comment: This is a great answer and one of the only answers on the internet I've managed to find that speaks about the $\pi/4$ phase-difference between the E and B fields in a good conductor. Do you know if there's any physical mechanism or reason behind this phase difference? I have posted a question about this over here https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/630956/phase-difference-between-electric-and-magnetic-fields-of-em-wave-in-a-conductor but I am yet to get an answer